# Trying to append an array to the bullets of Swiper.js using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, swiper.js

I am trying to convert the following into a more elegant solution, a loop perhaps:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
        var index;
        var a = ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three', 'Item Four', 'Item Five'];
        if (index === 0) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[0]) + '</span>';
        }
        if (index === 1) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[1]) + '</span>';
        }
         if (index === 2) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[2]) + '</span>';
        }
         if (index === 3) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[3]) + '</span>';
        }
         if (index === 4) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[4]) + '</span>';
        }
         if (index === 5) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[5]) + '</span>';
        }
    }
});

});
```

I have tried various loop techniques such as the ones in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript), especially this one:

```
var index;
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    console.log(a[index]);
}
```

Creating this as the loop:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
            var index;
            var a = ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three', 'Item Four', 'Item Five'];
            for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
                return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[index]) + '</span>';
            }
        }
    });
```

});

but this just displays the first item in the array for each bullet. I have created a [JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jenkinstudio/nv0mfy0z/#&togetherjs=IwdIG2m4Fq).

This is only for a prototype so the Array will not change, please can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swiper itself is repeated for five times and you don't need for loop again to iterate check solution on >> https://jsfiddle.net/nv0mfy0z/1/

```
var a = ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three', 'Item Four', 'Item Five'];

paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
       return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (a[index]) + '</span>';            
    }
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working anymore, and I'm not sure why. I'm going to open another question though, because it looks like mine is slightly different.